# Complex Java Permutation Generation Problem

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am trying to work out the best way to generate all possible permutations for a sequence which is a fixed number of digits and each digit has a different alphabet.

I have a number of integer arrays and each one can have different length and when generating the permutations only the values of the array can occupy the position in the final results.

A specific example is an int array called conditions with the following data:

```
conditions1 = {1,2,3,4}
conditions2 = {1,2,3}
conditions3 = {1,2,3}
conditions4 = {1,2}
conditions5 = {1,2}
```

and I want to create a 5 column table of all the possible permutations - this case 144 (4x3x3x2x2). Column 1 can only use the values from conditions1 and column 2 from conditions2, etc.

output would be :

```
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,2
1,1,1,2,1
1,1,1,2,2
1,1,2,1,1
.
.
through to 
4,3,3,2,2
```

It's been too long since since I've done any of this stuff and most of the information I've found relates to permutations with the same alphabet for all fields. I can use that then run a test after removing all the permutations that have columns with invalid values but sounds inefficient.

I'd appreciate any help here.

Z.

Comment: write some code, you will face problems, then ask questions - isn't it easier that way?

Comment: I did write some code. The problem is the code works well when each of the conditions is the same length. But when I try differing lengths as above it breaks down.

Comment: Then show the code, and we can help you change it to do the right thing. (By the way, *permutations* is not the right word (since you don't change the order) - *variation* would fit better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look ma, no recursion needed.

```
Iterator<int[]> permutations(final int[]... conditions) {
  int productLengths = 1;
  for (int[] arr : conditions) { productLengths *= arr.length; }
  final int nPermutations = productLengths;
  return new Iterator<int[]>() {
    int index = 0;
    public boolean hasNext() { return index < nPermutations; }
    public int[] next() {
      if (index == nPermutations) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
      int[] out = new int[conditions.length];
      for (int i = out.length, x = index; --i >= 0;) {
        int[] arr = conditions[i];
        out[i] = arr[x % arr.length];
        x /= arr.length;
      }
      ++index;
      return out;
    }
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  };
}
```

Wrapping it in an `Iterable<int[]>` will make it easier to use with a `for (... : ...)` loop.  You can get rid of the array allocation by doing away with the iterator interface and just taking in as argument an array to fill.

Comment: Thanks Mike. So much better. That works great. Just a quick question, do you mind explaining the theory behind the out[i] = arr[x % arr.length]; and x /= arr.length; lines as they are pretty much the guts of it.

Comment: @Zoran, even though it's not a recursive algorithm, you can think about it recursively.  If I have n elements in the first array, and o * p * q permutations from the rest of the arrays, then I can reduce the problem by picking one of the n using the remainder (`%`) and then dividing to get an index to use with the remaining arrays.